# How to remove mutability when creating an increasing value such as a position?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, processing, p5.js

I am trying to use a more functional approach in my code, and I have a variable `posx` which represents a position on the X axis.

It changes over time `xpos = xpos + pos`:

```
const createCircle = ({xpos, fill}) => {
 return {
   move: (pos) => {
     xpos = xpos + pos
     noStroke()
     ellipse( xpos,10,10,10)
   }
 }
}
```

How can I not mutate the variable `xpos`?

I've read that it is not good to mutate variables... so how would I do it then here?

Or is this ok in this case?

Rest of the code:

```
const circleOpts = {
  xpos: 20,
  fill: 0,
}

const createCircle = ({xpos, fill}) => {
 return {
   move: (pos) => {
     xpos = xpos + pos
     noStroke()
     ellipse( xpos,10,10,10)
   }
 }
} 

let bola;

function setup () {
  createCanvas(300,500)
  background(3)
  bola = createCircle(circleOpts)
}

function draw () {
 bola.move(10)
}
```

Comment: You're not actually mutating there - you're only *reassigning* (it's a primitive, after all - primitives are immutable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely fine in this case.

In your case, you're using a single variable to represent a single value. Since this value changes over time, it makes perfect sense that the variable would change over time.

Generally, I'd be very skeptical of claims that XYZ is **always** a good idea or **always** a bad idea. Everything depends on context.

Comment: What is *"absolutely fine"*? reassigning `xpos`? calling `noStroke` without arguments and discarding its return value? Discarding the return value of `ellipse`? Declaring variables without `const` or `let` or `var`?

Comment: @user633183 Yes, all of that is absolutely fine in this context.

Comment: @user633183 I'm not really sure what you mean? Flagging.

Answer (score -1):

This is a really broad question, but I'll give you my advice. Start looking at `setup` -

```
function setup () {
  createCanvas(300,500) // where is the canvas created?

  background(3)         // background(3)? 3?
                        // does this set the background? on what?

  bola = createCircle(circleOpts) // this is better
                                  // createCircle accepts an input and it returns a value
                                  // don't forget: const bola = ...

}
```

In general, you'll want to design functions that accept inputs and return outputs. Let's even think about the *types* of inputs and outputs they might have

```
createCircle : (x: Int, y: Int, r: Int) -> Element

moveCircle : (Element, x: Int, y: Int) -> Element

createCanvas : (h: Int, w: Int, bg: Int, elements: [Element]) -> Canvas

setBackground : (c: Canvas, bg: Int) -> Canvas

draw: (c: Canvas, e: Element) -> Canvas
```

Let's answer your question broadly here. We will implement `createCircle` which constructs a simple object. `moveCircle` will accept a Circle as input, but it will not mutate it -

```js
const createCircle = (x, y, r) =>
  ({ Element: "circle", x, y, r })

const moveCircle = (circle, x, y) =>
  createCircle       // <-- moveCircle creates a new circle
    ( circle.x + x   // using the circle's x value added to the new x
    , circle.y + y   // and the circle's y value added to the new y
    , circle.r       // the circle's radius, r, is unchanged
    )
    
const circle =
  createCircle (0, 0, 2)
  
const movedCircle =
  moveCircle (circle, -3, 3) // <-- circle is NOT mutated
  
console.log
  ( circle         // { Element: "circle", x: 0, y: 0, r: 2 }
  , movedCircle    // { Element: "circle", x: -3, y: 3, r: 2 }
  , circle         // { Element: "circle", x: 0, y: 0, r: 2 }
  )
```

We'll continue implementing more of your program. Each function has sensible parameters and produces an output

```
const createCanvas = (h = 100, w = 100, bg = 0, elements = []) =>
  ({ h, w, bg, elements })

const setBackground = (canvas, bg) =>
  createCanvas          // <-- similar technique as moveCircle
    ( canvas.h          // we create a new canvas using the canvas's height
    , canvas.w          // and the canvas's width
    , bg                // setting the new bg here
    , canvas.elements   // and keeping the existing canvas's elements
    )

const draw = (canvas, element) =>
  createCanvas          // <-- same technique as above
    ( canvas.h          // ...
    , canvas.w          // ...
    , canvas.bg         // same canvas bg this time
    , append            // append the new element to
        ( canvas.elements  // the canvas's elements
        , element
        )
    )

const append = (xs, x) =>
  xs .concat ([ x ])    // <-- immutability everywhere (ie, no [].push)
```

Lastly I'll introduce `render`. This is our side effect that takes a Canvas and renders it to the screen. A hallmark feature of side-effecting (impure) functions is that they have no return value (`null`, `undefined`, or *void*) -

```
render: (c: Canvas) -> Void

const render = (canvas) =>
{ console.log (`creating ${canvas.w}x${canvas.h} with bg:${canvas.bg}`)
  for (const elem of canvas.elements)
    console.log (`rendering`, elem)
}
```

This just "renders" the Canvas to the console, but the effect is the same. Write to stdout, a file, send it across the network, it doesn't matter; What matters is we kept everything pure up *until* this point.

Here's what a program might look like that uses our functions above -

```
const main = () =>
{ const canvas =
    setBackground               // set background
      ( createCanvas (300, 500) // on a 300x500 canvas
      , 3                       // to bg:3 (yellow?)
      )

  const circle =
    createCircle (0, 0, 2)

  render (draw (canvas, circle)) // <-- render is an efffect
  // creating 500x300 with bg:3
  // rendering { Element: "circle", x: 0, y: 0, r: 2 }

  const movedCircle =
    moveCircle (circle, -3, 3)

  render (draw (canvas, movedCircle)) // <-- effect
  // creating 500x300 with bg:3
  // rendering { Element: "circle", x: -3, y: 3, r: 2 }
}
```

You can verify the results in your own browser below

```js
const createCanvas = (h = 100, w = 100, bg = 0, elements = []) =>
  ({ h, w, bg, elements })

const setBackground = (canvas, bg) =>
  createCanvas
    ( canvas.h
    , canvas.w
    , bg
    , canvas.elements
    )

const createCircle = (x, y, r) =>
  ({ Element: "circle", x, y, r })
  
const moveCircle = (circle, x, y) =>
  createCircle
    ( circle.x + x
    , circle.y + y
    , circle.r
    )

const append = (xs, x) =>
  xs .concat ([ x ])

const draw = (canvas, element) =>
  createCanvas
    ( canvas.h
    , canvas.w
    , canvas.bg
    , append
        ( canvas.elements
        , element
        )
    )

const render = (canvas) =>
{ console.log (`creating ${canvas.w}x${canvas.h} with bg:${canvas.bg}`)
  for (const elem of canvas.elements)
    console.log (`rendering`, elem)
}
  
const main = () =>
{ const canvas =
    setBackground
      ( createCanvas (300, 500)
      , 3
      )

  const circle =
    createCircle (0, 0, 2)

  render (draw (canvas, circle))
  // creating 500x300 with bg:3
  // rendering { Element: "circle", x: 0, y: 0, r: 2 }
  
  const movedCircle =
    moveCircle (circle, -3, 3)
  
  render (draw (canvas, movedCircle))
  // creating 500x300 with bg:3
  // rendering { Element: "circle", x: -3, y: 3, r: 2 }
}

main ()
```

---

I want to briefly revisit `createCanvas` and change it from -

```
const createCanvas = (h = 100, w = 100, bg = 0, elements = []) =>
  ({ h, w, bg, elements })
```

to -

```
const createCanvas = (h = 100, w = 100, bg = 0, elements = []) =>
  ({ Element: "canvas", h, w, bg, elements })
```

This would allow canvases to be composed of other canvases. Designing composable data types is a cornerstone of functional programming -

```
const canvas =
  createCanvas
    ( 300
    , 500
    , 0
    , [ shape1, shape2, shape3 ]  // <-- containing a few elements ...
    )

const quadCanvas = (canvas) =>
  createCanvas
    ( canvas.h * 2
    , canvas.w * 2
    , canvas.bg
    , [ canvas, canvas, canvas, canvas ] // <-- rough example
    )

// 1 canvas       [%*$]

// quadCanvas     [%*$][%*$]
// (2x2)          [%*$][%*$]
```

Then our `render` function could expand to something more like -

```
const render = (canvas) =>
{ console.log (`creating ${canvas.w}x${canvas.h} with bg:${canvas.bg}`)
  for (const elem of canvas.elements)
    switch (elem.Element) {
      case 'circle': renderCirlce (elem) // <-- break complex tasks into smaller ones
      case 'line': renderLine (elem)

      case ...                           // <-- room for as many cases as you need

      case 'canvas': render (elem)       // <-- recursion! functional!

      default: throw Error (`cannot render unknown Element type: ${elem.Element}`)
        // <-- you must handle every scenario in your program
    }
}

const renderCircle = (circle) =>
{ ... }

const renderLine = (circle) =>
{ ... }

.... // <-- define element-specific renderers
```

Hopefully this gets your feet wet and gives you clearer picture of how to think about data and processes in a functional way.

Comment: Please note that a lot of this doesn't make a ton of sense in the P5.js context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer.. but its not very relevant in the context of p5js... and does not realy answer the question.

Comment: No worries. Functional programming is not relevant in the context of p5js. I never heard of it before answering this question. I hope you were able to learn something about functional programming anyway.